# The use of flip-flop operator in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I see the use of [flip-flop](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#index-entry-Flipflop_operator) in doc.perl6.org,  see the code below :

```
my $excerpt = q:to/END/;
Here's some unimportant text.
=begin code
This code block is what we're after.
We'll use 'ff' to get it.
=end code
More unimportant text.
=begin code
I want this line.
and this line as well.
HaHa
=end code
More unimport text.
=begin code
Let's to go home.
=end code
END

my @codelines = gather for $excerpt.lines {
    take $_ if "=begin code" ff "=end code"
}

# this will print four lines, starting with "=begin code" and ending with
# "=end code"

.say for @codelines;
=begin code
This code block is what we're after.
We'll use 'ff' to get it.
=end code
=begin code
I want this line.
and this line as well.
HaHa
=end code
=begin code
Let's to go home.
=end code
```

I want to save the lines between `=begin code` and `=end code` into separate arrays, such as this:

```
['This code block is what we're after.', 'We'll use 'ff' to get it.']
['I want this line.', 'and this line as well.', 'HaHa']
['Let's to go home.']
```

I know grammar can do this, but I want to know if there is a beter way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the matched values to not be included. You do this by adding `^` to the side of the operator you want excluded. In this case it is both sides of the operator.

You also need to collect the values up to have the grouped together. The simplest way in this case is to put that off between matches.
(If you wanted the endpoints included it would require more thought to get it right)

```perl6
my @codelines = gather {
  my @current;

  for $excerpt.lines {

    if "=begin code" ^ff^ "=end code" {

      # collect the values between matches
      push @current, $_;

    } else {
      # take the next value between matches

      # don't bother if there wasn't any values matched
      if @current {

        # you must do something so that you aren't
        # returning the same instance of the array
        take @current.List;
        @current = ();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need the result to be an array of arrays (mutable).

```perl6
if @current {
  take @current;
  @current := []; # bind it to a new array
}
```

---

An alternative would be to use `do for` with sequences that share the same iterator.
This works because `for` is more eager than `map` would be.

```perl6
my $iterator = $excerpt.lines.iterator;

my @codelines = do for Seq.new($iterator) {
    when "=begin code" {
        do for Seq.new($iterator) {
            last when "=end code";
            $_<> # make sure it is decontainerized
        }
    }
    # add this because `when` will return False if it doesn't match
    default { Empty }
}
```

`map` takes one sequence and turns it into another, but doesn't do anything until you try to get the next value from the sequence.
`for` starts iterating immediately, only stopping when you tell it to.

So `map` would cause race conditions even when running on a single thread, but `for` won't.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use good old regular expressions:

```
say ( $excerpt ~~ m:s:g{\=begin code\s+(.+?)\s+\=end code} ).map( *.[0] ).join("\n\n")
```

`s` for significant whitespace (not really needed), `g` for extracting all matches (not the first one), `.map` goes through the returned [Match object](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match) and extracts the first element (it's a data structure that contains the whole matched code). This creates a List that is ultimatelly printed with every element separated by two CRs.

Comment: This will not include lines that come between a `=begin code` and the end of the whole string if there's no `=end code` before it, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

another [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/ahfexj/idiomatic_way_to_pass_around_a_seq_or_iterator/) in reddit by [bobthecimmerian](https://www.reddit.com/user/bobthecimmerian), i copy it here for completeness:

```
my $excerpt = q:to/END/;
Here's some unimportant text.
=begin code
This code block is what we're after.
We'll use 'ff' to get it.
=end code
More unimportant text.
=begin code
I want this line.
and this line as well.
HaHa
=end code
More unimport text.
=begin code
Let's to go home.
=end code
END

sub doSomething(Iterator $iter) { 
    my @lines = [];
    my $item := $iter.pull-one;
    until ($item =:= IterationEnd || $item.Str ~~ / '=end code' /) {
       @lines.push($item);
       $item := $iter.pull-one;
    }
    say "Got @lines[]";
}
my Iterator $iter = $excerpt.lines.iterator;
my $item := $iter.pull-one;
until ($item =:= IterationEnd) {
    if ($item.Str ~~ / '=begin code' /) {
       doSomething($iter);
    }
    $item := $iter.pull-one;
}
```

the output is:

```
Got This code block is what we're after. We'll use 'ff' to get it.
Got I want this line. and this line as well. HaHa
Got Let's to go home.
```

Answer (score 2):

use grammar:

```
#use Grammar::Tracer;
#use Grammar::Debugger;

my $excerpt = q:to/END/;
Here's some unimportant text.
=begin code
This code block is what we're after.
We'll use 'ff' to get it.
=end code
More unimportant text.
=begin code
I want this line.
and this line as well.
HaHa
=end code
More unimport text.
=begin code
Let's to go home.
=end code
END

grammar ExtractSection {
    rule TOP      { ^ <section>+ %% <.comment> $      }
    token section { <line>+ % <.ws>                   }
    token line    { <?!before <comment>> \N+ \n       }  
    token comment { ['=begin code' | '=end code' ] \n }

}

class ExtractSectionAction {
    method TOP($/)      { make $/.values».ast }
    method section($/)  { make ~$/.trim       }
    method line($/)     { make ~$/.trim       }
    method comment($/)  { make Empty          }
}

my $em = ExtractSection.parse($excerpt, :actions(ExtractSectionAction)).ast;

for @$em -> $line {
    say $line;
    say '-' x 35;
}
```

Output:

```
Here's some unimportant text.
-----------------------------------
This code block is what we're after.
We'll use 'ff' to get it.
-----------------------------------
More unimportant text.
-----------------------------------
I want this line.
and this line as well.
HaHa
-----------------------------------
More unimport text.
-----------------------------------
Let's to go home.
-----------------------------------
```

But it included unrelated lines, based on @Brad Gilbert's solution,  I updated the above answer as follows(and thanks again):

```
#use Grammar::Tracer;
#use Grammar::Debugger;

my $excerpt = q:to/END/;
Here's some unimportant text.
=begin code
This code block is what we're after.
We'll use 'ff' to get it.
=end code
More unimportant text.
=begin code
I want this line.
and this line as well.
HaHa
=end code
More unimport text.
=begin code
Let's to go home.
=end code
END

grammar ExtractSection {
  token start   { ^^ '=begin code' \n          }
  token finish  { ^^ '=end code' \n            }
  token line    { ^^ \N+)> \n                  }
  token section { <start> ~ <finish> <line>+?  }
  token comment { ^^\N+ \n                     }
  token TOP     { [<section> || <comment>]+    } 
}

class ExtractSectionAction {
    method TOP($/)     { make @<section>».ast.List }
    method section($/) { make ~«@<line>.List       }
    method line($/)    { make ~$/.trim             }
    method comment($/) { make Empty                }
}

my $em = ExtractSection.parse($excerpt, :actions(ExtractSectionAction)).ast;

for @$em -> $line {
    say $line.perl;
    say '-' x 35;
}
```

Output is:

```
$("This code block is what we're after.", "We'll use 'ff' to get it.")
-----------------------------------
$("I want this line.", "and this line as well.", "HaHa")
-----------------------------------
$("Let's to go home.",)
-----------------------------------
```

So it works as expected.

Comment: That includes unwanted lines.

Comment: @BradGilbert oh, I'll fix that later

Comment: Why not structure it so that is handled for you `token start {^^'=begin code'\n};token finish {^^'=end code'\n};token line {^^\N+)>\n};token section {<start> ~ <finish> <line>+?};token comment {^^\N+\n};token TOP { [<section> || <comment>]+ }` `method TOP($/){make @<section>».ast.List};method section($/){make ~«@<line>.List}`

Comment: @BradGilbert Thank you very much, your solution works quite well! I'll updated here.

Answer (score 1):

It could be another solution, use [rotor](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/rotor)

```
my $excerpt = q:to/END/;
Here's some unimportant text.
=begin code
This code block is what we're after.
We'll use 'ff' to get it.
=end code
More unimportant text.
=begin code
I want this line.
and this line as well.
HaHa
=end code
More unimport text.
=begin code
Let's to go home.
=end code
END

my @sections =
gather for $excerpt.lines -> $line {
    if $line ~~ /'=begin code'/ ff $line ~~ /'end code'/  {  
      take $line.trim;
    }
}

my @idx = # gather take the indices of every `=begin code` and `=end code`
gather for @sections.kv -> $k, $v {
    if $v ~~ /'=begin code'/ or $v ~~ /'end code'/ {
        take $k;
    }
}

my @r = # gather take the lines except every line of `=begin code` and `=end code`
gather for @sections.kv -> $k, $v {
    if $v !~~ /'=begin code' | '=end code'/  {
        take $v;
    }
}

my @counts = @idx.rotor(2)».minmax».elems »-» 2;
say @r.rotor(|@counts).perl;
```

Output:

```
(("This code block is what we're after.", "We'll use 'ff' to get it."), ("I want this line.", "and this line as well.", "HaHa"), ("Let's to go home.",)).Seq
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer:

```
my $excerpt = q:to/END/;
Here's some unimportant text.
=begin code
This code block is what we're after.
We'll use 'ff' to get it.
=end code
More unimportant text.
=begin code
I want this line.
and this line as well.
HaHa
=end code
More unimport text.
=begin code
Let's to go home.
=end code
END

for $excerpt.comb(/'=begin code' \s* <( .+? )> \s+ '=end code' /) -> $c {
    say $c;
    say '-' x 15;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the [comb](https://docs.raku.org/routine/comb) operator:

```
my $str = q:to/EOS/;
Here's some unimportant text.
=begin code
This code block is what we're after.
We'll use 'ff' to get it.
=end code
More unimportant text.
=begin code
I want this line.
and this line as well.
HaHa.
=end code
More unimport text.
=begin code
Let's go home.
=end code
EOS

my token separator { '=begin code' \n | '=end code' \n }
my token lines { [<!separator> .]+ }

say $str.comb(
/
    <lines>       # match lines that not start with
                  # =begin code or =end code
    <separator>   # match lines that start with
                  # =begin code or =end code
    <(            # start capture
        <lines>+  # match lines between
                  # =begin code and =end code
    )>            # end capture
    <separator>   # match lines that start with
                  # =begin code or =end code
/).raku;
```

Output:

```
("This code block is what we're after.\nWe'll use 'ff' to get it.\n", "I want this line.\nand this line as well.\nHaHa.\n", "Let's go home.\n").Seq
```